# Adding 0x80000000 to register won't work when trying to build a mask

Tags: assembly, masking

Given the following code:

```
.section .rodata

input_format:  .string  "%d"
output_format1: .string  ""
output_format2: .string ""

.section .text
.globl  main
    .type main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,   %ebp

.loop:
    addl    $-4 ,%esp           # moving down the stack
    pushl   %esp
    pushl   $input_format
    call    scanf               # call scanf to get a number from the user
    addl    $8,%esp
    movl    (%esp),%edx         # get the new number

    movl    $0,%esi             # reseting first mask
    addl    $0x1,%esi           # first mask of 0x1
    movl    $0,%ecx             # reseting second mask
    addl    $0x80000000,%ecx

        // more code in the future

    # return from printf:

    movl    %ebp,%esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

I'm trying to build a mask in order to identify if a given number is a palindrome.
So I want to have to masks, first with all zeros and a "1" bit in the MSB, and the other
with all zeros and "1" bit in the LSB, and then run 16 times and compare the result using AND.
However, when writing  `addl    $0x80000000,%ecx` , the register `%ecx` won't get the immediate `0x80000000`. Why is that ?

Comment: After more thinking , I think that I need to write addl $0x8000,%ecx. Am I right ?

Comment: depends on which bit is meant for the flag.

Comment: I have 32 bits , so I need the LSB (left most) to be "1" , and then shift it right every iteration .

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure that there is no x86 opcode that will generate a full 4-byte literal value in one step.  One would think the assembler would complain, though.

Comment: What is a "full 4-byte literal value"?

Comment: @Hot Licks: You are wrong. You should check the Intel documentation (Software Developers Manual under `mov`) before making such a bold claim.

Comment: @JensBjörnhager -- Well, I haven't looked at the Intel documentation for about 20 years, but back then, to my recollection, there were instructions to load/add byte and HW literal/immediate values into regs, and instructions that would load/add a HW literal into the top of a 4-byte reg, but nothing that would load/add 4 bytes of literal (with every bit settable) in one operation.  But like I say, it's been 20 years, and I've looked at a half-dozen other opcode schemes in the interim, so I may be misremembering.

Comment: @Hot Licks What you describe sounds more like attributes of RISC architectures. (How to reference your name? :P)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "RISC", and there are many different (and divergent) definitions.

Comment: @HotLicks On ARM you had to and still have to load long immediate constants exactly the way you described. On Intel you could load 4-byte constants on the very first incarnation of their 32 bit architecture, the i386. So yes, you are misremembering and you seem to confuse those two instruction sets.
That does not depend on the definition of "RISC" - But as you sureley know back in those days ARM was considered to be a RISC and Intel a typical CISC instruction set, even if nowadays their definitions have become blurred.

Comment: @drhirsch -- Yeah, there've only been 2-3 RISC processors ever built, based on the original definition.  It's one of those terms that people define as they wish.  But I stand corrected on the Intel instruction set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is 0x80000000 + 0x80000000?  The result of that is why it doesn't seem to work.

To set the high bit no matter what, use the bit operations

```
 orl  $0x80000000, %ecx
```

Comment: Still doesn't work , the value of 'ecx' after the line you wrote is : -2147483648 .

Comment: @ron -- -2147483648 is 0x80000000.

Comment: Yes,I got that a minute after writing that comment. So I guess there won't be any trouble with AND-ing now each two bits and compare the result ..?

Comment: So why would that work and 0->ecx, add 0x80000000 to ecx not work?